# Process to automatically divide a loosely structured document into sub-sections?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

I have some documents that are semi-structured. All of them are job posts scraped from various sources. Every document has a requirements section, a qualifications section and so on.

The issue is that there is no fixed format for these. Sometimes, section names are bold, sometimes they are in h1, h2 tags and sometimes, they are same as rest of the text.

What would the process of dividing these documents into smaller parts called? Is there a known term for it that I could search for?